# Why we cannot extend disks with snapshots in vmware vSphere cloud?

Tags: extend, snapshot, vsphere

I know by the documentation of vSphere :
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vRealize-Suite-Lifecycle-Manager/2018/com.vmware.vrsuite.lcm.20.doc/GUID-E31CB588-6CDB-4064-96ED-1BF771914173.html?hWord=N4IghgNiBcIKYA8AucB2ATABOglgZwGs9M9UwAHPACwHsk8QBfIA

We cannot extend disks with snapshots in vmware vSphere cloud. I want to know the reason for a better understanding of vSphere.

Comment: You will get better understanding https://serverfault.com/questions/952889/cant-expand-drive-space-with-snapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not allowed. As it has no purpose. We cannot extend disks with snapshots in vmware vSphere cloud.